# How to show content of a MySQL table when the id is passed from one page to another?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a Table named table1 in Database named db1. Then, I have a fields named id, title and content in table1. When I clicked submit button in the page 'add.php' the data in add.php page will be added to 'Title' & 'content' fields.

Then, in the 'index.php' file, I want to show Title and Content. And I want to make the Title a URL links to 'view.php'. When the title url is clicked, it will load view.php, but how do I show the Content of the clicked Title in 'view.php' file?

**add.php**

```
mysql_query("insert into tb1(id, title, content)VALUES('', '$title', '$content')");
```

**index.php**

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="????">' . $row["title"] . '</a></td><td>' . $row["dtime"] . '</td></tr>';
```

I am asking what should I insert to the

```
<a href="">
```

value &

**view.php**

```
// What should be included on this page.
```

Comment: In the kindest way possible, stop. Sit down with any recent book or tutorial on MySQL and PHP, and start over.

Comment: I read the php & mysql tutorials in w3schools 2 times. But i don't know why is still do not understand.

Comment: While that resource is often discredited on this site, I know that its introduction to php and MySQL refers only to secure and non-deprecated APIs, so I don't think this code comes from there.

Comment: You have SQL injection security vulnerabilities in this code.

Comment: Thanks @halfer . I don't know about security yet, like to learn soon. But i am creating this project for my personal use then it will be not a problem for me, But can you kindly edit piyush's answer and fix the Security error?

Comment: I'd wager there's a few hundred thousand posts here with SQL injection issues, and it would be a fool's errand to try to fix them all. Indeed, I am very keen for Piyush to fix their post themselves. Meanwhile, if you are interested in how to write queries safely, search for "PHP SQL injection" on this site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I have understood is you want to make crud operation kind of module where you can insert in one table and then list from the table and view individual record by clicking from the list.
Once you insert the record should listed on index.php page, so you need to fetch all the records or if you want pagination you can add limit to query.ex 10 rows

```
Select * from table1 limit 0,10
```

Then you need to iterate the result to show data listing by applying loop. So you can create individual links in that loop which link to your view page

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="detail.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">' . $row["title"] . '</td><td>' . $row["dtime"] . '</td></a></tr>';
```

When clicking on detail page you can get the query string value and apply the where condition in query to get specific record.

```
Select * from table1 where Id='.$_GET[I'd].' limit 1
```

You can show these details on detail page...I hope I got your concern..

Comment: Thanks for the answer @piyush

Comment: Your last example has a SQL injection vulnerability, stemming from (a) not using bound parameters, (b) not filtering or validating user input before using it. This is a very serious security error, and will get people hacked when they copy it.